# how get metamask ethereum object when install both metamask and coinbase chrome extension?

Tags: coinbase-api, metamask

when I installed both `metamask` and `coinbase` chrome extension. `ethereum` object not work well.

Answer (score 0):

just use code like this:

```
async function findMetaMaskProvider() {
  const { providers } = (window as any).ethereum;
  let selectedProvider: any;
  for (const provider of providers || []) {
    if (provider.isMetaMask) {
      selectedProvider = provider;
    }
  }
  if (selectedProvider) {
    (window as any).ethereum.setSelectedProvider(selectedProvider);
    return selectedProvider;
  }
  return (window as any).ethereum;
}
```